# I want to display in combobox the items that contain the text I searched for

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I got combobox that contain names. My goal is to search with textbox for a string and than the names that start with this string will display in the combobox.

**for example:**

my combobox contain the next items:

> "Mark" , "Arik", "Michael"

when a user will write "`Mi`" in the textbox,  the combobox will display only "`Michael`".

P.S there is no button. only textbox and combobox.

Comment: Your combobx items are sorted or unsorted? Both way possible what you want but if sorted then solution will be easier and quicker. In sorted case when user will write `M` combobox will show Mark as both Mark and Michel start with M but Mark comes earlier and when `Mi` combobox will show Michel.

Comment: First the combobox is not sorted. Second my goal is to display Mark and Michael and not only Mark when user will write M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prepared you example.

In my example I use two additional assemblies:

1. Microsoft.Practices.Prism
2. System.Windows.Interactivity

XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="ComboBoxFilter.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        >
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SearchItems}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBox>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MySourceData}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel class:

```
class MainViewModel : NotificationObject
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            _myItems.Add("aaa");
            _myItems.Add("abb");
            _myItems.Add("aab");
            _myItems.Add("bbb");
            _myItems.Add("bcc");
            _myItems.Add("bbc");

            SearchItems = new DelegateCommand(this.OnSearchItems);
        }

        private string _searchText;
        public string SearchText
        {
            get { return _searchText; }
            set { _searchText = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => SearchText); }
        }

        private ICollectionView _mySourceData;
        public ICollectionView MySourceData
        {
            get { return CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_myItems); }           
        }

        private List<string> _myItems = new List<string>();

        public ICommand SearchItems { get; private set; }
        private void OnSearchItems()
        {            
            MySourceData.Filter = (o) => { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchText) ? true : (o as string).StartsWith(SearchText); };          
        }
    }
```

Do not forget set window DataContext in ctor:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
    }
```

[Here](http://sdrv.ms/PvYoLh) is all solution with additional assemblies (ComboBoxFilter.zip).

Comment: I got error that its not recognize the additional assemblies that you wrote, I wrote xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"> as u wrote but it give me an the next warning: assembly'System.Windows.Interactivity' was not found. Verify the you are not missing an assembly reference. Also, verify that your project and all referenced assemblies have been built. Because of that I got alot of error. can you add me please on skype? my id is dorz11. thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @DorZ11 I think that skype is not necessarily. I added you all solution on skydrive. So check this out! And I'm waiting on information from you.

Comment: First of all I really appraciate your effort to help me! Secondly, When I coppied the files to my project directory the directory of ComboBoxFilter has been copied ok but only 1 from the 3 files that were outside the directory been coppied succesfully and on its properties declared that his version doesn't recognized. could it be because I got VS9.0 2008 express?

Comment: @DorZ11, Yes probably this is the problem because i have VS2010. Here you have solution for this problem: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/80953/Converting-VS2010-Solution-to-VS2008 , try it and let me know.

Comment: I installed VS10 and now those are my errors: http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/7108/errorsn.jpg

Comment: @DorZ11 you must delete this assemblies from Reference and add it again from directory `ComboBoxFilter\ComboBoxFilter\bin\Debug\`. I think that would help you.

Comment: Omg! its worked mate!! WOW I cant believe it hehe.. thanks man! I was sure that I wont find my answer here but I wrong. your awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you use binding to populate the combobox you should just create text property and bind it to the textbox (two way mode binding).

In the setter of this property you just change the filtering condition of the earlier setup filtering for the view.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview.aspx

And in some cases you may wish to filter the collection not its view.
But it's you who decides.

Comment: I allready populate the combobox manually, I got an option to do it but without binding, with another textbox and button here's the code: private void Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { Names.Items.Add(SubmitNames.Text); } but its add items to the combobox only temporary: after I close the window and reopen it the items not saved.. how can I save them?

Comment: Then you still can get the view for ComboBox.Items